# Images are not getting displayed after build in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am displaying categories and their images. I get the categories from backend it also returns url. In developer mode emülatör(android) is displaying category images but when i try to build with npm build(react-native run-android --variant release) images are not showing up. I am sure that category data is coming. Images are coming from s3 bucket, i made them all public still no change. Couldn't find a solution about that. Showing up with npm run android but not after build.

```
<View style={{ borderColor:turkuazColor,borderStyle:"solid",borderWidth: 1,backgroundColor: whiteColor, width: width / 5, height: width / 5, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center", borderRadius: 99 }}>
    <Image source={{uri : img.uri}} resizeMode="contain" style={{ width: width / 6.5, height: width / 8.5, alignSelf: "center", marginBottom: 5 }} />
</View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, found a solution. In s3, static website hosting was enabled and i was trying to get the images from that url, however in developer mode it works but not after build. I started to use the url of s3 bucket which is different from the static hosting url

> static hosting has region information in url such as "us-east-3". Also added a CORS configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
   <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

and everythin is fine now.